# How can you cheaply add an overflow line to protect against blockage in a main line?

Tags: plumbing

I have 3/8" ID vinyl tubing water loop running through a unit that may create a blockage at some point.  Blockages can be self clearing or may require manual clearing.  In the case of a blockage within the unit, I would like to maintain water pressure by diverting the water around the unit.  However, I do not want to run any water through this 'overflow' line if the unit is functioning properly.

How is this best accomplished?  Is there a mechanical splitter that opens one branch only under a certain pressure?  Or would I need a flow sensor in the main line connected to a valve that can be automatically opened when flow rate drops?  The latter case adds more complexity and cost than the budget really allows for.

Comment: What you are describing is basically a silent auto-bypass: I'd be wary if this is a potable water supply and your 'unit' is a filter, as this will silently allow unfiltered water to the point-of-use. If this is for drinking water I'd advise against this, as you should be designing the system to be fail-safe (no water at all vs allowing untreated water through).

Comment: @gregmac Definitely a good point.  However, this is actually for a peltier-based water chiller.  I'm looking for protection against the peltiers freezing the water in the cooling blocks.  I can't seem to find a temperature control relay that handles more than 10A (I need 30A), and I trust a mechanical solution more than an electronic one anyway.

Comment: @Nicholas now i am extra curious as to what your project is.

Comment: @Alaskaman It's a peltier based cooling unit for a PC liquid cooling loop, designed to bring coolant temperatures sub-ambient after dissipating most of the heat through an air-cooled radiator.  It's relatively simple in theory, but trying to deal with all of the little complications is turning out to be quite the project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Mechanical

For a purely mechanical solution, you may be able to use a **pressure relief valve**, though this requires the pressure be high enough to trigger it.

[image: pressure relief valve]

These are fairly common parts, and a variation called a temperature and pressure (T&P) relief vale is installed on hot water tanks. You can get valves with varying pressure ratings/ranges.

I believe when operating near their set point, they do allow some amount of water through (eg, it is not a binary on/off) so you'd have to consider if this is acceptable for your use case (eg, if the pressure drops enough during normal usage that it doesn't normally let water by and if it's acceptable that some does go by).

I think this would really only work properly if your output flow is either zero (so pressure is equal to incoming) or full open (so pressure is minimal).

### Electrical

A bit more complex but perhaps more flexible way to do this would be to use a pressure switch on the output side:

[image: pressure switch]

This would come on when the pressure is low (you can dial these down to ~20psi or so), so if your output pressure gets too low normally, it would inadvertently trigger this.

You'd wire this to a solenoid on the bypass line.

[image: solenoid]